# Remove adjacent duplicate elements from a list

Tags: python

Google Python Class | List Exercise -

> Given a list of numbers, return a list where
>   all adjacent == elements have been reduced to a single element,
>   so [1, 2, 2, 3] returns [1, 2, 3]. You may create a new list or
>   modify the passed in list.

My solution using a new list is -

```
def remove_adjacent(nums):
  a = []
  for item in nums:
    if len(a):
      if a[-1] != item:
        a.append(item)
    else: a.append(item)        
  return a
```

The question even suggests that it could be done by modifying the passed in list. However, the python documentation warned against modifying elements while iterating a list using the for loop.

I am wondering what else can I try apart from iterating over the list, to get this done. I am not looking for the solution, but maybe a hint that can take me into a right direction.

**UPDATE**

-updated the above code with suggested improvements.

-tried the following with a while loop using suggested hints -

```
def remove_adjacent(nums):
  i = 1
  while i < len(nums):    
    if nums[i] == nums[i-1]:
      nums.pop(i)
      i -= 1  
    i += 1
  return nums
```

Comment: Don't use `<>`. The correct notation is `!=`. Use `if a`, not `if len(a) <> 0`.

Comment: @Aran-Fey IMHO both this question and the duplicate target should be closed as duplicates of [Removing elements that have consecutive duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5738901/7851470)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use a generator to iterate over the elements of the list, and `yield` a new one only when it has changed.

[`itertools.groupby`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) does exactly this.

You can modify the passed-in list if you iterate over a copy:

```
for elt in theList[ : ]:
    ...
```

Comment: when iterating over a copy, am I not modifying the *copy* and not the actual passed-in list?

Comment: Yes. You have to refer explicitly to the original list, using e.g. the index of the element.

Comment: I disagree with this. If you remove elements from the original list even when iterating over a copy you can make a number of mistakes. I think the best way to modify elements in a list one is iterating over is to iterate over the list backwards and modify the elements by index.

Comment: The answer: `list(x.next() for i, x in groupby(my_list))`

Comment: list(i for i, x in groupby(my_list))

Answer (score 20):

Here's the traditional way, deleting adjacent duplicates in situ, while traversing the list backwards:

```
Python 1.5.2 (#0, Apr 13 1999, 10:51:12) [MSC 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Copyright 1991-1995 Stichting Mathematisch Centrum, Amsterdam
>>> def dedupe_adjacent(alist):
...     for i in xrange(len(alist) - 1, 0, -1):
...         if alist[i] == alist[i-1]:
...             del alist[i]
...
>>> data = [1,2,2,3,2,2,4]; dedupe_adjacent(data); print data
[1, 2, 3, 2, 4]
>>> data = []; dedupe_adjacent(data); print data
[]
>>> data = [2]; dedupe_adjacent(data); print data
[2]
>>> data = [2,2]; dedupe_adjacent(data); print data
[2]
>>> data = [2,3]; dedupe_adjacent(data); print data
[2, 3]
>>> data = [2,2,2,2,2]; dedupe_adjacent(data); print data
[2]
>>>
```

**Update:** If you want a generator but (don't have `itertools.groupby` or (you can type faster than you can read its docs and understand its default behaviour)), here's a six-liner that does the job:

```
Python 2.3.5 (#62, Feb  8 2005, 16:23:02) [MSC v.1200 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> def dedupe_adjacent(iterable):
...     prev = object()
...     for item in iterable:
...         if item != prev:
...             prev = item
...             yield item
...
>>> data = [1,2,2,3,2,2,4]; print list(dedupe_adjacent(data))
[1, 2, 3, 2, 4]
>>>
```

**Update 2:** Concerning the baroque `itertools.groupby()` and the minimalist `object()` ...

To get the dedupe_adjacent effect out of `itertools.groupby()`, you need to wrap a list comprehension around it to throw away the unwanted groupers:

```
>>> [k for k, g in itertools.groupby([1,2,2,3,2,2,4])]
[1, 2, 3, 2, 4]
>>>
```

... or muck about with `itertools.imap` and/or `operators.itemgetter`, as seen in another answer.

Expected behaviour with `object` instances is that none of them compares equal to any other instance of any class, including `object` itself. Consequently they are extremely useful as sentinels.

```
>>> object() == object()
False
```

It's worth noting that the [Python reference code](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) for `itertools.groupby` uses `object()` as a sentinel:

```
self.tgtkey = self.currkey = self.currvalue = object()
```

and that code does the right thing when you run it:

```
>>> data = [object(), object()]
>>> data
[<object object at 0x00BBF098>, <object object at 0x00BBF050>]
>>> [k for k, g in groupby(data)]
[<object object at 0x00BBF098>, <object object at 0x00BBF050>]
```

**Update 3:** Remarks on forward-index in-situ operation

The OP's revised code:

```
def remove_adjacent(nums):
  i = 1
  while i < len(nums):    
    if nums[i] == nums[i-1]:
      nums.pop(i)
      i -= 1  
    i += 1
  return nums
```

is better written as:

```
def remove_adjacent(seq): # works on any sequence, not just on numbers
  i = 1
  n = len(seq)
  while i < n: # avoid calling len(seq) each time around
    if seq[i] == seq[i-1]:
      del seq[i]
      # value returned by seq.pop(i) is ignored; slower than del seq[i]
      n -= 1
    else:
      i += 1
  #### return seq #### don't do this
  # function acts in situ; should follow convention and return None
```

Comment: Python 1.5.2. Do you run it on FreeDOS?

Comment: @aaronasterling: No, on Windows XP, and only very occasionally, like when I see someone using itertools.groupby etc to do something simple ;-)

Comment: @John Machin. I like your algorithm a lot. +1 in a minute when my votes reup.

Comment: It's a bit hacky to do `prev = object( )` and hope that `object( )` isn't the first item in the iterable! It would be more correct, though slightly less elegant, to do `iterable = iter( iterable )` (to ensure that it is an *iterator*) and then `prev = next( iterable )`.

Comment: @katrielalex: All I'm hoping is that object() instances continue to be "featureless" ;-) Check out the results of `object() == object()` and `dir(object())` in any Python version from 2.2 onwards.

Comment: Heh, I didn't know that. I retract my previous statement!

Answer (score 8):

Just to show one more way here is another single liner version without indexes:

```
def remove_adjacent(nums):
     return [a for a,b in zip(nums, nums[1:]+[not nums[-1]]) if a != b]
```

The not part puts the last value to result as only a ends up to result.

Answer (score 6):

As usual, I am just here to advertise the impressive [recipes](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#recipes) in the Python itertools documentation.

What you are looking for is the function `unique_justseen`:

```
from itertools import imap, groupby
from operator import itemgetter

def unique_justseen(iterable, key=None):
    "List unique elements, preserving order. Remember only the element just seen."
    # unique_justseen('AAAABBBCCDAABBB') --> A B C D A B
    # unique_justseen('ABBCcAD', str.lower) --> A B C A D
    return imap(next, imap(itemgetter(1), groupby(iterable, key)))

list(unique_justseen([1,2,2,3])) # [1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 3):

Well, katrielalex is right about `itertools`, but the OP seems to be rather more interested (or should be!) in learning to manipulate the basics of the built-in data structures. As for manipulating a list in place, it does need thought, but my recommendation would be to read through [this section of the documentation](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html) and try a few list methods (hint: list.pop(), list.remove(), and learn everything about slices.)

The posted code could be simplified, by the way (you should however add handling of error conditions):

```
def remove_adjacent(nums):
  a = nums[:1]
  for item in nums[1:]:
    if item != a[-1]:
      a.append(item)
  return a
```

Comment: interesting to find, nums[0] returns an int, while nums[:1] returns a list with a single element! thank you!

Comment: *and* through the magic of slicing, `nums[:1]` will return an empty list if `nums` is empty, giving you correct behavior in case an empty list is provided as input. By contrast `nums[0]` would raise a `KeyError` if `nums` comes in as an empty list.

Answer (score 2):

Extremely elegant solution from  Google (source is here: https://developers.google.com/edu/python/exercises/basic):

```
def remove_adjacent(nums):
    result = []
    for num in nums:
        if len(result) == 0 or num != result[-1]:
            result.append(num)
    return result
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use list comprehension. For example something like this should do the job:

```
def remove_adjacent(L):
  return [elem for i, elem in enumerate(L) if i == 0 or L[i-1] != elem]
```

or:

```
def remove_adjacent(L):
  return [L[i] for i in xrange(len(L)) if i == 0 or L[i-1] != L[i]]
```

Answer (score 1):

`itertools.groupby` is superior, but there is also

```
reduce(lambda x, y: x + [y] if x[-1] != y else x, seq[1:], seq[0:1])
```

e.g.

```
>>> seq = [[1,1], [2,2], [3,3], [3,3], [2,2], [2,2], [1,1]]
>>> print reduce(lambda x, y: x + [y] if x[-1] != y else x, seq[1:], seq[0:1])
[[1, 1], [2, 2], [3, 3], [2, 2], [1, 1]]
```

When coming from functional languages where this sort of thing is done with a `fold`, then using `reduce` often feels natural.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
def remove_adjacent(nums):
  result = []
  if len(nums) > 0:
    result = [nums[0]]
    for i in range(len(nums)-1):
        if nums[i] != nums[i+1]:
            result.append(nums[i+1])

  return result
```

Answer (score 0):

@katrielalex's solution is more pythonic, but if you did need to modify the list in-place without making a copy, you could use a while loop and break when you catch an IndexError.
e.g.

```
nums = [1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,5,5,1,1,1]
def remove_adjacent(nums):
    """Removes adjacent items by modifying "nums" in-place. Returns None!"""
    i = 0
    while True:
        try:
            if nums[i] == nums[i+1]:
                # Letting you figure this part out, 
                # as it's a homework question
        except IndexError:
            break
print nums
remove_adjacent(nums)
print nums
```

Edit: [pastebin of one way to do it here](http://pastebin.com/U6U7ZE9U), in case you get stuck and want to know..

Comment: I tried out the hint and have updated with my attempt.

Answer (score 0):

You *can* modify a list you're iterating over if you use indices explicitly:

```
def remove_adjacent(l):
  if len(l)<2:
    return l
  prev,i = l[0],1
  while i < len(l):
    if l[i] == prev:
      del l[i]
    else:
      prev = l[i]
      i += 1
```

It doesn't work with iterators because iterators don't "know" how to modify the index when you remove arbitrary elements, so it's easier to just forbid it. Some languages have iterators with functions to remove the "current item".

Comment: (1) Don't use "l" as a variable name; in some fonts it looks too close to "1" (2) Your function returns the original list if its length is less than 2, otherwise it returns `None` ... somewhat inconsistent.

Comment: l is a perfectly good variable name. If your code font doesn't distinguish between l, I, 1, 0, O, then you need a better font.

Answer (score 0):

def remove_adjacent(nums):

```
newList=[]

for num in nums:

    if num not in newList:

        newList.append(num)

newList.sort()

return  newList
```

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach. Comments welcome.

```
def remove_adjacent(nums):
    '''modifies the list passed in'''
    l, r = 0, 1
    while r < len(nums):
        if nums[l] == nums[r]:
            r += 1
        else:
            l += 1
            nums[l] = nums[r]
            r += 1
    del nums[l+1:]
```

Answer (score 0):

Seeing the code written by Google is a humbling lol. This is what I came up with:

```
def remove_adjacent(nums):
   rmvelement = []
   checkedIndex = []
   for num in nums:
      if nums.index(num) not in checkedIndex:
         index = nums.index(num)
         checkedIndex.append(index)
         skip = False
      else:
         skip = True

   if skip == False:
      for x in nums[index+1:]:
         if x == num:
            rmvelement.append(x)
         else:
            break

   [nums.remove(_) for _ in rmvelement]
   return nums
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for a transparent (albeit roundabout) solution:

```
def remove_adjacent(nums):

    numstail = [i for i in range(0,len(nums))] 
    nums = nums + numstail

    for i in nums:
        if nums[i] == nums[i-1]:
            del nums[i]

    return nums[:-len(numstail)]
```

The logic is as follows:

- Create a tail-list equal to the length of the original list of numbers and append this to the end of the original list.
- Run a 'for-loop' that checks if a given element of nums is the same as the previous element. If so, delete it.
- Return the new nums list, with the necessary deletions, up to `len(numtails)` index positions from the end of the list.

(`numstail` is defined to avoid indices being out of range for any length list)

Answer (score 0):

```
def removeDupAdj2(a):
    b=[]
    for i in reversed(range(1,len(a))):
        if(a[i-1] == a[i]):
            del(a[i])
            #print(a)
    return a

a = [int(i) for i in '1 2 3 3 4 4 3 5 4 4 6 6 6 7 8 8 8 9 1 1 0 0'.split(' ')]
a

res = removeDupAdj2(a)
res
```

Answer (score -3):

Since you are in a Python class, I'm going to guess that you are new to the language. Thus, for you and any other beginners out there, I wrote a simple version of the code to help others get through the logic.

```
original= [1, 2, 2, 3]
newlist=[]

for item in original:
    if item in newlist:
        print "You don't need to add "+str(item)+" again."
    else:
        newlist.append(item)
        print "Added "+str(item)

print newlist
```

Comment: but it asks to remove only adjacent items, the above code will not let any duplicates in irrespective of their position, so inehrently [1,2,3,2] will produce [1,2,3] whereby it should produce [1,2,3,2]