# Python - Way to restart a for loop, similar to "continue" for while loops?

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, continue

Basically, I need a way to return control to the beginning of a for loop *and actually restart the entire iteration process* after taking an action if a certain condition is met.

What I'm trying to do is this:

```
    for index, item in enumerate(list2):
    if item == '||' and list2[index-1] == '||':
        del list2[index]
        *<some action that resarts the whole process>*
```

That way, if ['berry','||','||','||','pancake] is inside the list, I'll wind up with:

['berry','||','pancake'] instead.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you asking about nested loops?  `while something: for ...`?  If so, what's so complex? Please post a code sample to show what you're doing.

Comment: Can you provide some sample code so we can figure out what you're asking.  "continue" works for both "for" and "while" loops.  It looks like you want something different.

Comment: continue does not do this for while loops it merely skips the rest of the loop body, just as it does with for loops. Try rephrasing your question to describe what you're trying to accomplish instead of how you're trying to accomplish it

Comment: Yeah, I really have to wonder why you're trying to do this. Perhaps there's a better solution, if you look at the big picture.

Comment: Thanks guys. I've edited the original post with a code sample that explains what I'm trying to do!

Comment: While THC4k doesn't answer the question, it is a good way to solve your original problem. If you insist on deleting items from the list, you are better off to just use a single while loop and managing the index yourself

Answer (score 44, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by "restarting". Do you want to start iterating over from the beginning, or simply skip the current iteration?

If it's the latter, then `for` loops support `continue` just like `while` loops do:

```
for i in xrange(10):
  if i == 5:
    continue
  print i
```

The above will print the numbers from 0 to 9, except for 5.

If you're talking about starting over from the beginning of the `for` loop, there's no way to do that except "manually", for example by wrapping it in a `while` loop:

```
should_restart = True
while should_restart:
  should_restart = False
  for i in xrange(10):
    print i
    if i == 5:
      should_restart = True
      break
```

The above will print the numbers from 0 to 5, then start over from 0 again, and so on indefinitely (not really a great example, I know).

Comment: Thanks a hell of a lot! The second solution is brilliant.

Comment: No problem. Also have a look at Nathon's answer, it has a cleaner/simpler version of this using `for`'s `else` clause.

Comment: Haha that second example smells like C++ so bad

Answer (score 27):

```
while True:
    for i in xrange(10):
        if condition(i):
            break
    else:
        break
```

That will do what you seem to want. Why you would want to do it is a different matter. Maybe you should take a look at your code and make sure you're not missing an obvious and easier way to do it.

Comment: As clarification (since `for: ... else:` can be kind of confusing and this also has `break`s in two nested loops): if the condition is true, it breaks out of the `for` loop, which means it skips the `else` part of that loop, which means it goes back to the top of the `while` loop. If the condition is always false, it completes the `for` loop, goes into the `else` part, and `break`s from the `while` loop.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for. It's very clean, but a bit unintuitive that you cloud write this in python.

Answer (score 5):

> some action that resarts the whole process

A poor way to think of an algorithm.

You're just filtering, i.e., removing duplicates.

And -- in Python -- you're happiest making copies, not trying to do `del`.  In general, there's very little call to use `del`.

```
def unique( some_list ):
    list_iter= iter(some_list)
    prev= list_iter.next()
    for item in list_iter:
        if item != prev:
            yield prev
            prev= item
    yield prev

list( unique( ['berry','||','||','||','pancake'] ) )
```

Answer (score 4):

The inevitable itertools version, because it just came to me:

```
from itertools import groupby

def uniq(seq):
    for key, items in groupby(seq):
        yield key

print list(uniq(['berry','||','||','||','pancake'])) # ['berry','||', 'pancake']
# or simply:
print [key for key, items in groupby(['berry','||','||','||','pancake'])]
```

Comment: +1, I would have just returned a generator expression though

Answer (score 3):

`Continue` will work for any loop.

Comment: But I'm looking for a way to restart the for loop entirely...control goes back to the state it was in at the beginning.

Comment: Good reference for this: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Python_Programming/Flow_control#Breaking.2C_continuing_and_the_else_clause_of_loops

Answer (score 3):

`continue` works in for loops also.

```
>>> for i in range(3):
...     print 'Before', i
...     if i == 1:
...             continue
...     print 'After', i
... 
Before 0
After 0
Before 1
# After 1 is missing
Before 2
After 2
```

Comment: Thanks--that's good to know! But I'm looking for a way to restart the for loop entirely...control goes back to the state it was in at the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see answering your question leads to some rather convoluted code. Usually a better way can be found, which is why such constructs aren't built into the language

If you are not comfortable using itertools, consider using this loop instead. Not only is it easier to follow than your restarting for loop, it is also more efficient because it doesn't waste time rechecking items that have already been passed over.

```
L = ['berry','||','||','||','pancake']
idx=1
while idx<len(L):
    if L[idx-1]==L[idx]:
        del L[idx]
    else:
        idx+=1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def remove_adjacent(nums):
     return [a for a,b in zip(nums, nums[1:]+[not nums[-1]]) if a != b]

example = ['berry','||','||','||','pancake']

example = remove_adjacent(example)
print example
""" Output:
['berry', '||', 'pancake']
"""
```

And by the way this is repeating of [Remove adjacent duplicate elements from a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3460161/remove-adjacent-duplicate-elements-from-a-list/3463143#3463143)