# how to restart "for" loop in python ?

Tags: python, python-2.7, for-loop

How can I do this in python:

```
x = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
for i in x:
    if i == 4:
       -restart the loop from beginning-
    else:
        print i
```

So here it will print till 4 then repeat the loop

Comment: what do you mean by 'repeat'? do you mean print (1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4) etc.?

Comment: I would use a recursive function defining the loop as a function

Comment: I would use [`itertools.cycle`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle).

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3704918/python-way-to-restart-a-for-loop-similar-to-continue-for-while-loops), second option

Comment: What would be the purpose of that? Why not just do `while True: for i in range(1, 5):`?

Comment: For context, is there a language you *can* do this in? I mean, restart a loop at the beginning of an iterable object using a foreach-type syntax? (Obviously you can do it if you're looping over indices.)

Comment: Sorry if it sound bit confusing. It is a part of my code. The main idea is that while I am looping if I detected an **X** variable I want to restart the loop from beginning

Comment: @Meran: What will be your exit condition? Or do you plan on looping forever?

Comment: @JoelCornett No i don't want to loop for ever

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What about this:

```
x = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
restart = True
while restart:
    for i in x:
        # add any exit condition!
        # if foo == bar:
        #   restart = False
        #   break
        if i == 4:
           break
        else:
            print i
```

Comment: Could also put `print i` before the `if` statement, and remove `else`

Answer (score 2):

Something like this perhaps?  But it will loop forever...

```
x = [ ..... ]
restart = True
while restart:
    for i in x:
        if i == 4:
            restart = True
            break
        restart = False
        print i
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't directly. Use *itertools.cycle*

```
for idx, val in enumerate(itertools.cycle(range(4))):
    print v
    if idx>20:
        break
```

*idx* is used to break infiniteloop

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap in a while statement.

```
while True:
    restart = False
    for i in x:
        if i == 4:
            restart = True
            break
        else:
            print i
    if not restart:
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

With a while loop:

```py
x=[1,2,3,4,5,6]
i=0
while i<len(x): 
    if x[i] == 4:
        i=0
        continue
    else:
        print x[i]
    i+=1
```

Answer (score -3):

I would use a recursive function for that

```
def fun(x):
    for i in x:
        if i == 4:
            fun(x)
        else:
            print i
    return;

x = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
fun(x)
```

Comment: You're going to get a `RuntimeError` for exceeding the maximum recursion limit very quickly. The default is `1000`.

Comment: How many times does author want to repeat?

Comment: recursive functions are dangerous for high values of recursion, and are a lot hard to integrate exit conditions into.

Comment: ok, I agree, I remove the post than?

Comment: You click **delete** @freude