# Python Filtering a Point Cloud with PhotoScan Based on a Threshold Value - basic python help needed

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to implement a filter with Python to sort out the points on a point cloud generated by [Agisoft](https://www.agisoft.com/) PhotoScan. PhotoScan is a photogrammetry software developed to be user friendly but also allows to use Python commands through an [API](https://www.agisoft.com/pdf/photoscan_python_api_1_4_2.pdf).

Bellow is my code so far and I'm pretty sure there is better way to write it as I'm missing something. The code runs inside PhotoScan.

### Objective:

Selecting and removing 10% of points at a time with error within defined range of 50 to 10. Also removing any points within error range less than 10% of the total, when the initial steps of selecting and removing 10% at a time are done. Immediately after every point removal an optimization procedure should be done. It should stop when no points are selectable or when selectable points counts as less than 1% of the present total points and it is not worth removing them.

---

### Draw it for better understanding:

[image: Drawing the logic...]

### Actual Code Under Construction *(3 updates - see bellow for details)*:

```
import PhotoScan as PS
import math

doc = PS.app.document
chunk = doc.chunk


# using float with range and that by setting i = 1 it steps 0.1 at a time
def precrange(a, b, i):
    if a < b:
        p = 10**i
        sr = a*p
        er = (b*p) + 1
        p = float(p)
        for n in range(sr, er):
            x = n/p
            yield x
    else:
        p = 10**i
        sr = b*p
        er = (a*p) + 1
        p = float(p)
        for n in range(sr, er):
            x = n/p
            yield x


"""
Determine if x is close to y:
    x relates to nselected variable
    y to p10 variable

math.isclose() Return True if the values a and b are close to each other and
False otherwise

var is the tolerance here setted as a relative tolerance:
rel_tol is the relative tolerance – it is the maximum allowed difference
between a and b, relative to the larger absolute value of a or b. For example,
to set a tolerance of 5%, pass rel_tol=0.05. The default tolerance is 1e-09,
which assures that the two values are the same within about 9 decimal digits.
rel_tol must be greater than zero.

"""


def test_isclose(x, y, var):
    if math.isclose(x, y, rel_tol=var):  # if variables are close return True
        return True
    else:
        False


# 1. define filter limits
f_ReconstUncert = precrange(50, 10, 1)

# 2. count initial point number
tiePoints_0 = len(chunk.point_cloud.points)  # storing info for later

# 3. call Filter() and init it
f = PS.PointCloud.Filter()
f.init(chunk, criterion=PS.PointCloud.Filter.ReconstructionUncertainty)

a = 0
"""
Way to restart for loop!

should_restart = True
while should_restart:
  should_restart = False
  for i in xrange(10):
    print i
    if i == 5:
      should_restart = True
      break

"""
restartLoop = True
while restartLoop:
    restartLoop = False

    for count, i in enumerate(f_ReconstUncert):  # for each threshold value
        # count points for every i
        tiePoints = len(chunk.point_cloud.points)
        p10 = int(round((10 / 100) * tiePoints, 0))  # 10% of the total

        f.selectPoints(i)  # selects points

        nselected = len([p for p in chunk.point_cloud.points if p.selected])
        percent = round(nselected * 100 / tiePoints, 2)

        if nselected == 0:
            print("For threshold {} there´s no selectable points".format(i))
            break
        elif test_isclose(nselected, p10, 0.1):
            a += 1
            print("Threshold found in iteration: ", count)

            print("----------------------------------------------")
            print("# {}      Removing points from cloud          ".format(a))
            print("----------------------------------------------")
            print("# {}. Reconstruction Uncerntainty:"
                  " {:.2f}".format(a, i))
            print("{} - {}"
                  " ({:.1f} %)\n".format(tiePoints,
                                         nselected, percent))

            f.removePoints(i)  # removes points

            # optimization procedure needed to refine cameras positions
            print("--------------Optimizing cameras-------------\n")
            chunk.optimizeCameras(fit_f=True, fit_cx=True,
                                  fit_cy=True, fit_b1=False,
                                  fit_b2=False, fit_k1=True,
                                  fit_k2=True, fit_k3=True,
                                  fit_k4=False, fit_p1=True,
                                  fit_p2=True, fit_p3=False,
                                  fit_p4=False, adaptive_fitting=False)

            # count again number of points in point cloud
            tiePoints = len(chunk.point_cloud.points)
            print("= {} remaining points after"
                  " {} removal".format(tiePoints, a))
            # reassigning variable to get new 10% of remaining points
            p10 = int(round((10 / 100) * tiePoints, 0))
            percent = round(nselected * 100 / tiePoints, 2)
            print("----------------------------------------------\n\n")

            # restart loop to investigate from range start
            restartLoop = True
            break

        else:
            f.resetSelection()
            continue  # continue to next i
    else:
        f.resetSelection()
        print("for loop didnt work out")


print("{} iterations done!".format(count))
tiePoints = len(chunk.point_cloud.points)
print("Tiepoints 0: ", tiePoints_0)
print("Tiepoints 1: ", tiePoints)
```

### Problems:

**A.** Currently I'm stuck on an endless processing because of a loop. I know it's about my bad coding. But how do I implement my objective and get away with the infinite loops? **ANSWER:** Got the code less confusing and updated above.

**B.** How do I start over (or restart) my search for valid threshold values in the *range(50, 20)* after finding one of them? **ANSWER:** [Stack Exchange: how to restart a for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3704967/9801767)

**C.** How do I turn the code more pythonic?

---

### IMPORTANT UPDATE 1: *altered above*

Using a better range with float solution adapted from [stackoverflow: how-to-use-a-decimal-range-step-value](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24683593/9801767)

```
# using float with range and that by setting i = 1 it steps 0.1 at a time
def precrange(a, b, i):
    if a < b:
        p = 10**i
        sr = a*p
        er = (b*p) + 1
        p = float(p)
        return map(lambda x: x/p, range(sr, er))
    else:
        p = 10**i
        sr = b*p
        er = (a*p) + 1
        p = float(p)
        return map(lambda x: x/p, range(sr, er))

# some code
f_ReconstUncert = precrange(50, 20, 1)
```

And also using *[math.isclose()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html)* to determine if selected points are close to the 10% selected points instead of using a manual solution through assigning new variables. This was implemented as follows:

```
"""
Determine if x is close to y:
    x relates to nselected variable
    y to p10 variable

math.isclose() Return True if the values a and b are close to each other and
False otherwise

var is the tolerance here setted as a relative tolerance:
rel_tol is the relative tolerance – it is the maximum allowed difference
between a and b, relative to the larger absolute value of a or b. For example,
to set a tolerance of 5%, pass rel_tol=0.05. The default tolerance is 1e-09,
which assures that the two values are the same within about 9 decimal digits.
rel_tol must be greater than zero.

"""


def test_threshold(x, y, var):
    if math.isclose(x, y, rel_tol=var):  # if variables are close return True
        return True
    else:
        False

# some code

if test_threshold(nselected, p10, 0.1):
    # if true then a valid threshold is found
    # some code
```

---

### UPDATE 2: *altered on code under construction*

Minor fixes and got to restart de for loop from beginning by following guidance from another [Stack Exchange](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3704967/9801767) post on the subject. Have to improve the range now or alter the isclose() to get more values.

```
restartLoop = True
while restartLoop:
    restartLoop = False
    for i in range(0, 10):
        if condition:
            restartLoop = True
            break
```

---

### UPDATE 3: Code structure to achieve listed objectives:

```
threshold = range(0, 11, 1)
listx = []
for i in threshold:
    listx.append(i)

restart = 0
restartLoop = True
while restartLoop:
    restartLoop = False
    for idx, i in enumerate(listx):
        print("do something as printing i:", i)

        if i > 5:  # if this condition restart loop
            print("found value for condition: ", i)
            del listx[idx]
            restartLoop = True
            print("RESTARTING LOOP\n")
            restart += 1
            break  # break inner while and restart for loop
        else:
            # continue if the inner loop wasn't broken
            continue
    else:
        continue

print("restart - outer while", restart)
```