# recursively remove adjacent duplicates in a list

Tags: python, recursion

I looked up and found a close example, but the answer found in this link: [Remove adjacent duplicate elements from a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3460161/remove-adjacent-duplicate-elements-from-a-list)  won't run the test cases for this problem. So this is all I have so far:

```
def remove_dups(thelist):
    """Returns: a COPY of thelist with adjacent duplicates removed.

    Example: for thelist = [1,2,2,3,3,3,4,5,1,1,1],
    the answer is [1,2,3,4,5,1]

    Precondition: thelist is a list of ints"""
    i = 1
    if len(thelist) == 0:
        return []
    elif len(thelist) == 1:
        return thelist
    elif thelist[i] == thelist[i-1]:
        del thelist[i]
    return remove_dups(thelist[i:])


def test_remove_dups():
    assert_equals([], remove_dups([]))
    assert_equals([3], remove_dups([3,3]))
    assert_equals([4], remove_dups([4]))
    assert_equals([5], remove_dups([5, 5]))
    assert_equals([1,2,3,4,5,1], remove_dups([1,2,2,3,3,3,4,5,1,1,1]))

# test for whether the code is really returning a copy of the original list
    mylist = [3]
    assert_equals(False, mylist is remove_dups(mylist))
```

EDIT while I do understand that the accepted answer linked above using itertools.groupby would work, I think it wouldn't teach me what's wrong with my code & and would defeat the purpose of the exercise if I imported grouby from itertools.

Comment: Must it be recursive? Can you sort it and then iterate over it?

Comment: I would think sorting would be wrong, else you'd just do sorted(set(list))

Comment: @andyG yes, it has to be recursive

Comment: @AaronHall: Ah yeah, the `set` function. I'm still learning Python myself!

Comment: @AndyG It's actually the constructor for the `set` datatpype, [read the data model documentation for more.](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from itertools import groupby

def remove_dups(lst):
    return [k for k,items in groupby(lst)]
```

If you really want a recursive solution, I would suggest something like

```
def remove_dups(lst):
    if lst:
        firstval = lst[0]

        # find lowest index of val != firstval
        for index, value in enumerate(lst):
            if value != firstval:
                return [firstval] + remove_dups(lst[index:])

        # no such value found
        return [firstval]
    else:
        # empty list
        return []
```

Answer (score 0):

Your assertion fails, because in

```
return thelist
```

you are returning the same list, and not a copy as specified in the comments.

Try:

```
return thelist[:]
```

Comment: You're right, but that doesn't change what I end up with - I think I need to alter the last three lines of the first set of code.

Answer (score 0):

When using recursion with list it is most of the time a problem of returning a sub-list or part of that list. Which makes the termination case testing for an empty list. And then you have the two cases:

1. The current value is different from the last one we saw so we want to keep it
2. The current value is the same as the last one we saw so we discard it and keep iterating on the "rest" of the values.

Which translate in this code:

```
l = [1,2,2,3,3,3,4,5,1,1,1]

def dedup(values, uniq):
  # The list of values is empty our work here is done
  if not values:
    return uniq
  # We add a value in 'uniq' for two reasons:
  #  1/ it is empty and we need to start somewhere
  #  2/ it is different from the last value that was added
  if not uniq or values[0] != uniq[-1]:
    uniq.append(values.pop(0))
    return dedup(values, uniq)
  # We just added the exact same value so we remove it from 'values' and 
  # move to the next iteration
  return dedup(values[1:], uniq)

print dedup(l, []) # output: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1]
```

Comment: Thank you for the indepth explanation - I appreciate the comments between lines.

Answer (score 0):

problem is with your return statement,

you are returning

```
return remove_dups(thelist[i:])
```

output will be always last n single element of list

like for above soon,

```
print remove_dups([1,2,2,3,3,3,4,5,1,1,1])
>>> [1] #as your desired is [1,2,3,4,5,1]
```

which returns finally a list of single element as it don't consider Oth element.

here is recursive solution.

```
def remove_dups(lst):
    if len(lst)>1:

        if lst[0] != lst[1]:
            return [lst[0]] + remove_dups(lst[1:])

        del lst[1]
        return remove_dups(lst)
    else:
        return lst
```

Comment: you're right! I kept getting just the one value. Thank you.

Comment: i have edited answer for solution, you can review it. i think its more better solution.