# Python Removing Adjacent Numbers

Tags: python

```
# D. Given a list of numbers, return a list where
# all adjacent == elements have been reduced to a single element,
# so [1, 2, 2, 3] returns [1, 2, 3]. You may create a new list or
# modify the passed in list.


def remove_adjacent(nums):
  previous =''
  for i in nums:
    if i == previous:
      nums.remove(i)
    else:
      previous = i
  return nums
```

Hi can someone explain why my code doesn't work. It outputs [2,3,3] instead of [2,3] for the input [2,2,3,3,3]

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207406/remove-items-from-a-list-while-iterating

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3460161/remove-adjacent-duplicate-elements-from-a-list

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove items from a list while iterating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207406/remove-items-from-a-list-while-iterating)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem arises when you remove items from a list you are iterating over. Iteration works like this: each index in a list is visited once, from beginning to end. When you delete something, the contents of the list are shifted left:

```
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | << your list
| 1 | 2 |   | 4 | 5 | << 3 is deleted
| 1 | 2 | 4 | 5 | << the list fills in the gap
```

However, the index of the iterator doesn't know the rest of the list has changed one index to the left, so it advances.

Normally, this is how a list iterates:

```
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 
      ^ < index of iterator
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 |
          ^ The index advances, all is good.
```

When you delete terms, though, this is what happens:

```
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 |
      ^ index
| 1 | 2 | 4 | 5 | 
          ^ Oops! The iterator skips over the missing 3, and never gets to it.
```

You can fix this in your by manually iterating through the indices, only advancing if a deletion was *not* made:

```
def remove_adjacent(nums):
    previous = ''
    i = 0;
    while i < len(nums):
        if nums[i] == previous:
            nums.remove(i)
        else:
            previous = nums[i]
            i+=1
    return nums
```

This avoids having to make a soft copy of the list with [:] (although that is another approach)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi thank you for the answer! There's a small mistake though I think u meant nums.remove(nums[i]) instead of nums.remove(i)

Comment: Oh yeah, of course! Although you also could use list.pop(index) :)

Answer (score 1):

Take a copy of the list and iterate over it first else the iteration will fail with unexpected results

```
def remove_adjacent(nums):
    previous = ''
    for i in nums[:]: # using the copy of nums
        if i == previous:
            nums.remove(i)
        else:
            previous = i
    return nums

>>> remove_adjacent([2,2,3,3,3])
[2, 3]
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer, do you mind explaining why slicing creates a copy of the list? Also what is the purpose of using a copy instead of the original list

Comment: here we are iterating over the copy, so when you modify the original list, you do not modify the copy that you iterate over.