# Given a list of numbers return a list in which all equal adjacent elements have been reduced to a single element

Tags: python

I need to write a code that Given a list of numbers return a list in which all
equal adjacent elements have been reduced
to a single element.
example:
list=[1,1,3,4,5,5,6,7,7,7,8,5,7]
becomes
[1,3,4,5,6,7,8,5,7]

i wrote this code:

```
list = []
list1 = []
for i in range(10):
  c = input("inserisci un numero: ")
  list.append(c)
k = 0
for i in range(len(list)-1):
  
  if  list[i+1] != list[i]:
    list1[k].append(list[i])
    k+=1

print(list1)
```

ut it's giving me index error could you explain me why?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Removing Adjacent Numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44858453/python-removing-adjacent-numbers)

Comment: don't shadow build-in functions, i.e. choose a different name for your list: `list_`, `lst`, ... because `list` has a special meaning, [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-list). [and that's why has a different highlighting scheme]

Answer (score 2):

You want `list1.append(list[i])`, not `list1[k]`.  The `k` variable is useless.

The reason it explodes is that, the first time through the second loop, you refer to `list1[0]`, but `list1` is empty.  It has no elements, so index 0 is out of bounds.

Answer (score 0):

Add the first element to result list

```
result.append(list[0])
```

then just loop from 1 to the end of the original list.

On each iteration just check `if list[i-1] != list[i]:` if true add to result list like this `result.append(list[i])`

Answer (score 0):

Using `itertools.groupby` function from the standard library you can group similar terms.

```
import itertools as it
l = [1,1,3,4,5,5,6,7,7,7,8,5,7]

ll = []
_ = [ll.append(next(grp)) if check else ll.append(grp) for check, grp in it.groupby(l)]
print(ll)
```